# Split text into array with two-words

Tags: php

I know how to split a text into an array:

```
$wordArray = preg_split('#\PL+#u', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

I want to split the text into two-worded parts, so the array doesn't include single words. How to do that?

Comment: Use a loop that iterates over your one-word array and always puts 2 together.

Comment: Maybe something like '#\PL+\s\PL+#u' would work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use

```
$wordArray = preg_split('#([\w\']+\W+[\w\']+)\W+#u', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Comment: I do not quite undestand about single quotes. Can you show me an example (what is your in, and what is your out) ?

Comment: From `what's` it makes `what s`, so it removes the single quote.

Comment: Oh, you may to set enumeration of needed symbols, for quotes it seems: `'#([\w\']+[^\w]+[\w\']+)[^\w]+#u'`.

Comment: And to prevent it, when the quote at the begin or at the end of word, you make build a monster, like this `'#\'?([\w\']+\W+[\w\']+?)\'?\W+#u'`

Comment: Actually it was better to use @user1781026's solution, but I appreciate your efforts. Thanks!